# .OBJ groups and Unity

Tags: import, unity-game-engine, assets, .obj

I have an .OBJ file (which looks like [this](http://www.3dvieweronline.com/share/jT7ILRSIkxVadMd/jT7ILRSIkxVadMd)) and when I import the file into Unity (4.5.3f3) the second group (Square_Plane) does not import.

The .OBJ contains the following:

```
mtllib test.mtl
g Triangle_Plane.001
v -2.210575 0.000000 -0.986309
v -2.210575 0.000000 1.013691
v -4.210576 0.000000 1.013691
usemtl (null)
s off
f 1 3 2

g Square_Plane
v 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
usemtl (null)
s off
f 4 7 6 5
```

This is what it looks like outside of Unity:
[image: Should be:]
Then in Unity:
[image: Fail]
Have I done something wrong in my .OBJ file, or does anyone know if there is an import setting or similar for Unity which will fix this issue?

Comment: A value of -0 is weird. Don't think it would cause an error, but still weird.

Comment: I just removed the (-0)'s.. no difference. But thanks for the reply :)

Comment: -0 isn't really weird, you'll see this quite often when you log floating point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file defines a quad. Unity doesn't like quads. If you split it up in two triangles it works:

```
mtllib test.mtl
g Triangle_Plane.001
v -2.210575 0.000000 -0.986309
v -2.210575 0.000000 1.013691
v -4.210576 0.000000 1.013691
usemtl (null)
s off
f 1 3 2

g Square_Plane
v 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
usemtl (null)
s off
f 4 7 6
f 4 6 5
```

[image: Obj succesfully imported in Unity]

Comment: Interesting, I will investigate when I have a chance, thanks for the reply.!